# Trying to scrape data off a website which requires a data range and drop down options using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am attempting to scrape data off of this website: https://a100.gov.bc.ca/pub/hbs/opq/ftas/invoiceSummary.do but am struggling to figure out how to specify a specific date range and options from a drop down. I have very little experience with Rvest and RSelenium, so any help is appreciated.

My specific tasks are:

1. specify the date range from January 2022 to December 2022
2. Run the search individually for all options in File type
3. Change the product tab from "logs" to "all"
4. Then hit the Send Data File button and send to my email

if anybody has any pointers or advice please let me know.

So far I have attempting to use the Rvest package:

```
HBW_url <- "https://a100.gov.bc.ca/pub/hbs/opq/ftas/invoiceSummary.do?actionType=P400&radSelectedReport=billing"

page <- read_html(HBW_url) 
page %>%
    html_element('body') %>%
    html_text('From')`
```

but am unsure how to select the specific properties I need.

Comment: unsure how this website works- when I click on Configure PDF Report, the page refreshes. Send XML sends me to an error page? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy4H5.png

Comment: I think it is required to specify "Client No/Loc". Otherwise I also get an error after clicking on "Send XML".

Comment: thanks @Till is there a particular Client No/Loc you want to use D-Whiz?

Comment: I don't have to specify Client No/Loc in order download data.

Comment: Could you double-check your described workflow in Inconito mode of your browser so you'd start from a clean session? It apparently pre-fills the form with previous values and we probably see a bit different state than you - https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ZAr.png . And either use exact values and control labels or illustrate it with an annotated screenshot. E.g:  From: "202201", To:  "202212", ... , Click "Send XML" .  Rigth now I'm not that sure what you mean by "run the search" or is "Send Data File" the same as "Send XML" or am I actually seeing a different view.

Comment: Hello, it looks like we are seeing a different search. https://imgur.com/a/yEVTR4X is what I see. and I am interested in the Send Data File button at the bottom of https://a100.gov.bc.ca/pub/hbs/opq/ftas/invoiceSummary.do?actionType=P400&radSelectedReport=billing